# Calculating Timestamp difference - doesnt work beyond 48 hours

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I am calculating difference between two timestamps, which somehow doesn't work when difference is more than 48 hours.

This is my code:
`select systimestamp, mystoredtimestamp, 
extract( hour from diff ) || ' hours ' || extract( minute from diff ) || ' minutes' 
     from (select (systimestamp - mystoredtimestamp)) diff from dual)`

The output is

```
1. systimestamp: 30-OCT-17 11.48.43.783572 AM +00:00,
2. mystoredtimestamp: 27-OCT-17 07.30.36.956687 AM,
3. difference: 4 hours 18 minutes
```

(somehow this markdown numbering is not being rendered, the above are the three different columns of the query)

mystoredtimestamp is in `TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` datatype. Is that whats causing the problem? If so, how do I resolve this now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract days as well.  It won't automatically convert to number of hours.

```
SELECT
  extract ( DAY FROM diff )
  || ' days '
  ||extract( hour FROM diff )
  || ' hours '
  || extract( minute FROM diff )
  || ' minutes'
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      systimestamp - CAST ( '27-OCT-17 07.30.36.956687 AM' AS TIMESTAMP(6)
      WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE ) diff
    FROM
      DUAL
  );
```

**O/p**

```
3 days 2 hours 26 minutes
```

If you want in hours, multiply by 24 and add days.

```
SELECT
  24 * extract ( DAY FROM diff )
   +
 extract( hour FROM diff )
  || ' hours '
  || extract( minute FROM diff )
  || ' minutes'
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      systimestamp - CAST ( '27-OCT-17 07.30.36.956687 AM' AS TIMESTAMP(6)
      WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE ) diff
    FROM
      DUAL
  );
```

**O/p**

```
74 hours 28 minutes
```